# частичная выборка

Tags: sql

Есть структура

```
tbl1
 ID | Name
1   |Vasia
2   |Petia
3   |Fedor
4   |Ivan

tbl2
ID | Date
1 | 02.06.2006
3 | 01.08.2004
```

Нужно вывести полностью все имена и в поле Даты только даты которые больше 01.02.2005

Я пришёл к этому, но этот запрос выводит только одно имя и дату, а нужно все.

```
SELECT g.Name, b.Date 
FROM tbl1 g
JOIN tbl2 b ON b.ID = g.ID
WHERE b.Date >= '01.02.2005'
```

Comment: А ничего что судя по вашей "структуре" только у первой записи id >= '01.02.2005'?

Comment: Да, должно получиться: Vasia | 02.06.2006 Petia | null Fedor | null Ivan | null

Comment: WHERE действует для всего запроса. Если вам надо добавить дату только для тех, у кого она > конкретной даты то это в join'е надо указывать аля `JOIN tbl2 b ON b.ID = g.ID AND b.Date >= '01.02.2005'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  g.Name,
  b.Date 
FROM
  tbl1 g
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 b ON (
    b.ID = g.ID AND
    b.Date >= '01.02.2005'
  )
```